# Text hyperlink in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am building a code on flutter, this is a login form and bellow this there is a text called Sign Up, I want to put external website url. Can anyone help me on this?

[This is the screen looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhsBP.jpg)

**This is the code**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:academy_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:academy_app/models/common_functions.dart';
import 'package:academy_app/providers/auth.dart';
import 'package:academy_app/screens/forgot_password_screen.dart';
import 'package:academy_app/screens/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/auth';
  const AuthScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _AuthScreenState createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final Map<String, String> _authData = {
    'email': '',
    'password': '',
  };

  bool hidePassword = true;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Color getColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    const Set<MaterialState> interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
      MaterialState.pressed,
      MaterialState.hovered,
      MaterialState.focused,
    };
    if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
      return Colors.blue;
    }
    return Colors.red;
  }

  InputDecoration getInputDecoration(String hintext, IconData iconData) {
    return InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
      ),
      focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
      ),
      border: const OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(12.0),
        ),
      ),
      focusedErrorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFF65054)),
      ),
      errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFF65054)),
      ),
      filled: true,
      prefixIcon: Icon(
        iconData,
        color: kTextLowBlackColor,
      ),
      hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 14),
      hintText: hintext,
      fillColor: kBackgroundColor,
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18, horizontal: 15),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _submit() async {
    if (!globalFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      // Invalid!
      return;
    }
    globalFormKey.currentState!.save();

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      // Log user in
      await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).login(
        _authData['email'].toString(),
        _authData['password'].toString(),
      );

      // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', (r) => false);
      CommonFunctions.showSuccessToast('Login Successful');
    } on HttpException {
      var errorMsg = 'Auth failed';
      CommonFunctions.showErrorDialog(errorMsg, context);
    } catch (error) {
      // print(error);
      const errorMsg = 'Could not authenticate!';
      CommonFunctions.showErrorDialog(errorMsg, context);
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        elevation: 0,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: kSelectItemColor),
        backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Form(
                key: globalFormKey,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    ),
                    elevation: 0,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 25,
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/do_login.png',
                            height: 70,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          'Log in',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 17.0, bottom: 5.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Email',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 15.0, top: 0.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 8.0),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                            decoration: getInputDecoration(
                              'Email',
                              Icons.email_outlined,
                            ),
                            controller: _emailController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            validator: (input) =>
                            !RegExp(r"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")
                                .hasMatch(input!)
                                ? "Email Id should be valid"
                                : null,
                            onSaved: (value) {
                              _authData['email'] = value.toString();
                              _emailController.text = value as String;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 17.0, bottom: 5.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Password',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 15.0, top: 0.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 4.0),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            controller: _passwordController,
                            onSaved: (input) {
                              _authData['password'] = input.toString();
                              _passwordController.text = input as String;
                            },
                            validator: (input) => input!.length < 3
                                ? "Password should be more than 3 characters"
                                : null,
                            obscureText: hidePassword,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                borderSide:
                                BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                                borderSide:
                                BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                              ),
                              border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(12.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 14),
                              hintText: "password",
                              fillColor: kBackgroundColor,
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 18, horizontal: 15),
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                Icons.lock_outlined,
                                color: kTextLowBlackColor,
                              ),
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    hidePassword = !hidePassword;
                                  });
                                },
                                color: kTextLowBlackColor,
                                icon: Icon(hidePassword
                                    ? Icons.visibility_off_outlined
                                    : Icons.visibility_outlined),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context)
                                .pushNamed(ForgotPassword.routeName);
                          },
                          child: const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                              child: Text(
                                'Forget Password?',
                                style: TextStyle(color: kSecondaryColor),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: _isLoading
                              ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                              : Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            child: MaterialButton(
                              elevation: 0,
                              color: kRedColor,
                              onPressed: _submit,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 20, vertical: 16),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(10),
                                // side: const BorderSide(color: kRedColor),
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: const [
                                  Text(
                                    'Log In',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Do not have an account?',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: kTextLowBlackColor,
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SignUpScreen.routeName);
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      ' Sign up',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 17,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am building a code on flutter, this is a login form and bellow this there is a text called Sign Up, I want to put external website url. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use url_launcher Package. url_launcher: ^6.1.14 https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

use launchUrl Method & pass url to this method

```
InkWell(
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    await launchUrl(
                                        Uri.parse('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207132/text-hyperlink-in-flutter')); // Add URL which you want here
                                    // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SignUpScreen.routeName);
                                  },
                                  child: const Text(
                                    ' Sign up',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It works, but it's opening within chrome. Actually I've added deeplink and it's not working if the url is opening within the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RichText or just `Row[Text1,Text2ForSignUp]`

```dart
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(children: [
    TextSpan(text: "Don't have an account? "),
    TextSpan(
      text: "Sign Up",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
        ..onTap = () {
          print("Sign Up");
        },
    ),
  ]),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to put external website url

If you mean that it should open a website in a browser then you can use the pub package url_launcher https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

And use it like so:

```
      onPressed: () async {
        if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse(urlString))) {
          throw Exception('Could not launch $urlString');
        }
```