# Flutter chrome external launcher

Tags: flutter

I am building a code on flutter, this is a login form and bellow this there is a text called Sign Up, I want to put external website url. Can anyone help me on this?

I was using bellow code but it launch external url within the app. Can anyone help me so when I click the text it will launch chrome browser.

```
InkWell(
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    await launchUrl(
                                        Uri.parse('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207132/text-hyperlink-in-flutter')); // Add URL which you want here
                                    // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SignUpScreen.routeName);
                                  },
                                  child: const Text(
                                    ' Sign up',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Can anyone help me so when I click the text it will launch chrome browser.

Comment: Have you followed the configuration for iOS and Android here? https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#configuration

Comment: onTap: () async {
                      await launchUrl(
                          Uri.parse('https://contact.clickslearn.com'));
                          mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication,// Add URL which you want here
                      // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SignUpScreen.routeName);
                    },

Comment: Tried but no help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open **external browser** not **inAppBrowser**, then you should set `mode` to `LaunchMode.externalApplication`  like this:

```
await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url),
        mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)
```